# wordpress plugin page error

Tags: plugins

i get an error on plugin page:
An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which plugin is it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an error in WordPress core displayed when the WordPress core can't reach the WordPress.org update servers. Usually, it will go away on its own - minor issue with reaching WordPress.org, or, if it persists, it could point to some configuration error on your server preventing WordPress in reaching to WordPress.org servers for update checks.